# How to (correctly/efficiently) move a btrfs subvolume containing snapshots?

Tags: linux, btrfs, snapshot, snapper

I have btrfs as the filesystem for configuring root, and configured my system to use snapper for backup.

The `/@arch-root/@.snapshots/` subvolume contains several sub-dir each containing several subvolumes, all of which are snapshots of my *system* root (`/@arch-root/`, a subvolume on its own). Now I want to move `@.snapshots` to under the actual *filesystem* root `/`, to smoothline the whole flow of rollback. How can I do the moving?

(Apparently, I'm moving them **inside** the same filesystem / partition.)

In particular, it appears `mv` can move subvolumes (containing internal subvolumes), but I am not sure of its effect (particularly about disk consumption / CoW / internal linkage between file blocks) in this case. If the files were small, I'd simply use this; but in my scenario there are lots of snapshots and them being huge.

Below is an explanation of the whole situation, in case further details are helpful (I believe not, but just in case).

---

### Full case description

Initially, I made an unideal layout of the filesystem, as illustrated below (where everything starting with `@` denotes a subvolume):

```
/
  @arch-root/
    @.snapshots/
      1234/
        @snapshot/
    var/
      @log/
```

where `/` denotes the root of the filesystem, `@arch-root` is the system root of my archlinux (which is mounted to `/` during start-up), and `@.snapshots` is the place I store the snapshots created by snapper about my system root

As `@.snapshots` is managed by snapper, it contains internal sub-dirs each containing a descriptor file and a snapshot of my system root (`@arch-root`).

Now, when I look back, I realised this is unideal. If I need to rollback to a previous version, I cannot easily do so -- the directories like `var/log` will not be mounted correctly to the snapshot. There are also some other directories managed by docker having similar issues.

Thus, it looks like the best way is to move every important directory to under `/`, and configure `fstab` to mount them to the correct location during boot. The new filesystem layout will be like this:

```
/
  @arch-root/
  @.snapshots/
    1234/
      @snapshot/
  @var-log/
```

And `fstab` would mount filesystems like this (where `a    == b` means `b` in the actual filesystem is mounted to `a`):

```
/    == /@arch-root/
  .snapshots/    == /@.snapshots/
  var/
    log/    == /@var-log/
```

But to do so, I'll need to figure out the correct way of moving them: because they contain internal subvolumes (including snapshots), the moving should not create redundant copies of the data. That leads to the question.